# Calling a sub within a loop

Tags: vba

was trying to call a sub(trialMacro) from inside another sub(Macro2) but somehow it does not get activated. Is there a reason why? The call function works fine if its not within the loop. I.e. if I just do a plain call function under another sub. Is my coding right? I'm not sure if the loop disrupts the execution

```
  ' trial Macro
Sub trialMacro()
Dim PrevCell As Range
Set PrevCell = ActiveCell
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:= _
       "$M$2,$M$3,$M$5,$M$7"
   SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    'Copy in sample and out of sample error
    PrevCell.Resize(1, 3).Copy

    'Paste Values of in sample and out of sample errors
    PrevCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Copy Co-efficient
    Range("M2:M7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    'Select paste destination
    PrevCell.Offset(0, 7).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    'Copy Paste Following months data
    PrevCell.Offset(1, -1).Resize(12, 1).Copy

    'Select target destination
    PrevCell.Offset(0, 13).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
PrevCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
    Dim i, j As Integer

    For i = 50 To 162
    For j = 0 To 113
    Sheets("Model v2 DUBDAT >0").Cells(i, 17).Select
    Call trialMacro
    Range("P50:BA50").Offset(j, 0).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Reference Sheet").Select
    Range("D6").Offset(j, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Model v2 DUBDAT >0").Select
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You should try assign Objects instead of so many **`.Select`** and **`Selection`**. The way you use **Call** is fine here.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a read...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx

Remove call from this line

```
Call trialMacro
```

Should be..

```
trialMacro
```

If you use the call statement the subname must be followed by parentheses.

Comment: hmmm, I realised there is a problem with my first loop as well in that it doesn't go down the column. any inputs?